# ngRoute return 404 Not Found error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a simple personal contacts management app using AngularJS. I put all my files inside `htdocs/angular-contacts/` folder of my Mac machine.

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='ContactsApp'>
    <head>
        <title>Contacts</title>
        <base href='/'></base>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Contacts</h1>
        <div ng-view=""></div>
        <script src='/angular-contacts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
        <script src='/angular-contacts/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script src='/angular-contacts/angular-route.min.js'></script>
        <script src='/angular-contacts/angular-route.min.js.map'></script>
        <script src='/angular-contacts/app.js'></script>
        <script src='/angular-contacts/controller.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('ContactsApp', ['ngRoute']);
    .config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/contacts',{
                controller: 'ListController',
                templateUrl: 'list.html'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('ContactsApp')
    .controller('ListController',function($scope){
        $scope.contacts = [];
    })
```

**list.html**

```
<p>List views...</p>
```

Why I go to `http://localhost:8888/angular-contacts/contacts`, I got 404 Not Found error.

How to fix this problem? How to load that `list.html`?

**Note**:

1. I'm using MAMP (Apache).
2. AngularJS: v1.3.14
3. Angular Route: v1.3.14

Comment: This question has been asked an answered many times.  if you use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`, you MUST enable link rewriting on your server as well.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 1):

That's because

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/contacts',{
        controller: 'ListController',
        templateUrl: 'list.html'
    });
```

expects the `http://localhost:8888/contacts` location, not the `http://localhost:8000/angular-contacts/contats` location.

You should add the prefix in your route declaration, or even better, [conifgure the virtual host](http://sawmac.com/mamp/virtual/), so you'll be able to use a real domain, rather than the localhost's sub-catalogue.